# How Can I Enable a Multi-Lingual Catalog Block on Drupal 6.32 + Ubercart 6.x-2.13

Tags: shopping-cart, multilingual, ubercart, language-switching

### Description of Problem

No matter what I try, I cannot get my Ubercart Catalog Block to change languages when I use the Language Switcher.  You can test this behaviour for yourself at:

**holistichorsecare.com/zh/products/aromadog-arf-ritis-pain-relief-1oz**

Regardless of the language context (English or Chinese, "en" or "zh-hant"), the shopping cart block on the left margin of the page, under all circumstances, displays this text:

**Shopping cart**

**There are no products in your shopping cart.**

**0 Items   Total: HK$ 0.00**

Go ahead and give it a try.  Load the page and click on English or Chinese as they appear in the page header.  The shopping cart block does not change languages- and I'd like it to.

### The Localization Files are Installed - I Think...

I've installed the following localization strings packages using the Administration front end and they appeared to be loaded correctly.

- ubercart-6.x-2.13.zh-hant.po
- uc_ajax_cart-6.x-1.0.zh-hant.po

### Checking out the Module Code

Looking into:

holistichorsecare.com/www/content/sites/all/modules/ubercart/uc_cart/translations/zh-hant

I see the following entry around line 1926:

msgid "There are no products in your shopping cart."
msgstr "ä½ (å¦³)ç
                 è³¼ç©è»è£¡æ²æä»»ä½åå."

(the garbled text is the multi-byte characters breaking up in my shell)

Looking into

holistichorsecare.com/www/content/sites/all/modules/ubercart/uc_cart/cart.module

I see the following call around line 706:

```
$output = '<p class="uc-cart-empty">'. t('There are no products in your shopping cart.') .'</p>';
```

So it appears that there is a call to t() to translate the string, but none is forthcoming from whatever system there is that serves up the alternatives.

Can someone please tell me where I need to go in the administration front end to enable localization/translation for the shopping cart block (ajax cart) in Ubercart?

I'm thinking I just missed a check box somewhere to turn on the translation, or have to tell Drupal/Ubercart that the strings in the Shopping Cart Block are to be translated, but I don't know where to go or how to do this.

P.S.:  When I called i18n_get_lang() in troubleshooting code I got the right answer back (i.e. "en" or "zh-hant"), so the system knows what language context it is in.

Thank you.

## UPDATE - SUCCESS!

I managed to get this working by importing zh-hant strings into the *Built in Interface*.

Here's how I did it:

1) I went to **Site building » Blocks** and confirmed that the **Shopping Cart** block Language setting was set to **All Languages**

2) I went to **Site configuration » Languages » Configure » Language Negotiation** and set the Language negotiation setting to **Path prefix with language fallback**

3) I went to **Site building » Translate interface** and selected the **Import** Tab

4) On the Import tab, I clicked on **Choose File** button and then selected **ubercart-6.x-2.13.zh-hant.po**, which holds a bunch of Chinese definitions.  I got this definitions file from **localize.drupal.org/translate/languages/zh-hant**

5) I selected **Built-in Interface** and **Existing strings are kept, only new ones are added**

6) I then clicked on **IMPORT**

### Verification

Once the import was complete, I clicked on the **Overview** tab to check the results:

Chinese, Traditional    4242/9881 (42.93%)  0/19 (0%)   0/16 (0%)   0/49 (0%)   0/37 (0%)   0/15 (0%)   1518/1518 (100%)    2/3 (66.67%)

Apparently, this import loaded **4242** definitions into the **Built-in Interface** section of the Drupal system.  These strings are nowhere near the Store Administration area, which is a bit of a mystery to me, but hey - it worked.

### Conclusion

Once I had completed the above steps, the Shopping Cart Block began to display correctly in Chinese or English depending on which language was selected with the Language Switcher.

### Final Comment & A Question

On second thought, maybe this is not so counter-intuitive after all.  After all, the BLOCK is part of the General Interface of the Drupal System, not specifically a part of the Checkout process.

Maybe I'm wrong about this...can anyone confirm or correct?

### g.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The procedure you did is correct, code which calls `t()` will create a create a string (usually under the `Built-in Interface` group) and needs to be translated manually by searching for a string, or by importing a `.po` file which contains the necessary strings into that group.

What makes the behaviour a little more bizarre if you're not familiar with it is that because `t()` only creates interface strings at call-time, you must view the content in the desired language first (even though it will be broken / no translations). This allows `t()` to create the string entries in the database, which allows you to subsequently translate them.

I would recommend that you use a module such as [l18n_update](https://www.drupal.org/project/l10n_update) to keep your interface translations up to date automatically and import strings for any new changes made upstream.

Comment: Hello Stewart.  

I did what you suggested.  I installed https://www.drupal.org/project/l10n_update.  

It updated 128 missing string areas!  Wow!  Anyway, once the process was over the Overview tab looked like this:  

Chinese, Traditional 6732/10372 (64.91%) 0/19 (0%) 0/16 (0%) 0/49 (0%) 0/37 (0%) 0/15 (0%) 1518/1518 (100%) 2/3 (66.67%)

AND many of the places where ENGLISH was appearing instead of CHINESE now display correctly.  Thanks for the tip regarding viewing "broken" content to generate empty string slots to then fill with the update process, I'll keep that in mind.